# Does FFMPEG supports AES encryption

Tags: encryption, ffmpeg

Want to know if the ffmpeg has in-built encryption . I have grabbed the frames from the camera and now I encode the video with this frame using ffmpeg. 
But is it possible to encrypt the frames (AES) just like we mention the encode format.

Comment: Are you asking whether ffmpeg supports CENC and the common file format for DRM purposes? I any case, this is not a programming question.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, `ffmpeg` supports [AES](https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/blob/bb3703a4c30659d7ae7b41a94455ce810bbc102b/libavutil/aes.c).

You can create encrypted HLS segments for example using:

```
ffmpeg -i <input> -hls_time 10 -hls_key_info_file key_info playlist.m3u8
```

The same lib is also used for `SRTP` and possibly other formats.

If you want to encrypt just the I-frames you'll most likely need to write a custom program using the `ffmpeg` libs.

Answer (score 0):

Yes Support AES Encryption

```
#!/bin/bash

 mkdir -p /opt/FFMPEG/rawContent/

  cd /opt/FFMPEG/rawContent/

        mkdir -p /opt/FFMPEG/$1/processed/
        mkdir -p /opt/FFMPEG/$1/encrypted/

        var=`ls | grep  -i 'mp4'`
        for z in ${var}

           do
                    cd /opt/FFMPEG/$1/encrypted/
                    fname=`echo ${z} | awk -F "." '{print $1}'`
                    BASE_URL=" ${fname}.key"
                    openssl rand 16 > ${fname}.key
                    echo $BASE_URL > ${fname}.keyinfo
                    echo ${fname}.key >> ${fname}.keyinfo
                    echo $(openssl rand -hex 16) >> ${fname}.keyinfo

                    fname=`echo ${z} | awk -F "." '{print $1}'`
                    sleep 1

                    ffmpeg  -i /opt/FFMPEG/rawContent/${fname}.mp4 -profile:v baseline -level 4.0  -start_number 0 -hls_time 10 -hls_list_size 0 -hls_key_info_file ${fname}.keyinfo* -f hls ${fname}.m3u8

                    mv /opt/FFMPEG/rawContent/${fname}.mp4 /opt/FFMPEG/$1/processed/

            done
  cd -
```

Run above Shell as 
./shellname.sh NameOfTheFolder

> (./test.sh  TestOne)